# How to create a smooth zoom in and out animation onclick using a-frame

Tags: html, animation, aframe

I've been reading through the [a-frame docs on animations](https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/core/animations.html). When I **click** on an entity, I would like for it to scale smoothly forwards and then backwards i.e. `from` -> `to` -> `from`

Perhaps there is a simple solution, but the closest I've gotten so far is using this:

```
<a-animation 
 attribute='scale'
 dur='500'
 from='1 1 1'
 to='3 3 3'
 fill='backwards'
 begin='click'>
</a-animation>
```

`fill='backwards'` brings the animation back to the `from` state after the animation is finished, but it doesn't do so smoothly.

---

Is there a simple way to animate `from` -> `to` -> `from`?

Here is a sample below:

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aframe/0.7.1/aframe.js'></script>

<a-scene>
  <a-entity camera look-controls>
    <a-entity geometry='primitive: ring;radiusOuter: 0.10;radiusInner: 0.05;' material='color: red;' position='0 0 -3' cursor='maxDistance: 30; fuse: false'>
    </a-entity>
  </a-entity>

  <a-entity geometry='primitive:box' position='0 0 -5'>
    <a-animation attribute='scale' dur='500' from='1 1 1' to='3 3 3' fill='backwards' begin='click'></a-animation>
  </a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/core/animations.html):
Direction - determines the direction of the animation. Use Alternate
Make it repeat once, so the animation goes back to it's starting position.

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aframe/0.7.1/aframe.js'></script>

<a-scene>
  <a-entity camera look-controls>
    <a-entity geometry='primitive: ring;radiusOuter: 0.10;radiusInner: 0.05;' material='color: red;' position='0 0 -3' cursor='maxDistance: 30; fuse: false'>
    </a-entity>
  </a-entity>

  <a-entity geometry='primitive:box' position='0 0 -5'>
    <a-animation attribute='scale' dur='500' direction='alternate' from='1 1 1' to='3 3 3' begin='click' repeat='1'></a-animation>
  </a-entity>
</a-scene>
```